# How can I increase volume mediaplayer sound in kotlin compose?

Tags: kotlin

I've been doing for a while dictionary app and I want the word to be heard aloud, so I made the word listen button. It's working properly but for some reason it sounds a bit low when I'm listening so I want to turn the volume up a bit how can I do that? I am sharing my codes below

I am making the dictionary application in kotlin and using compose.

**phoneticSound function**

```
fun phoneticSound(_audioUrl:String){



    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    var audioUrl = _audioUrl



    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioUrl)
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()

    } catch (e: Exception) {


        e.printStackTrace()
    }


}
```

This function receives a string. This string is the url of the audio source. I am playing the audio with mediaPlayer using this url.

How can I adjust the sound by adding an add-on to the codes I've made?

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer has the 'setVolume()' function, which you can use to set the volume. You can set values from 0.0 - 1.0 (0-100%).

source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float)